# Using Pyqt with Twitters API

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, twitter, pyqt

I am trying to build a GUI for my Twitter application that automatically follows people. I have it mostly working in the console, however I am trying to convert it into a GUI, and am running into a few issues. The main problem is that whenever I assign the script I want to run when a button is pushed, it either runs immediately when I run the app, which wont display the GUI; or the GUI displays, but the  function on the button does nothing. I have been looking for days, but I do not know what the problem is.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import time
import tweepy
from keys import keys
import requests_cache
from random import randint
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from subprocess import call
import sys
from AddToDB import *



SCREEN_NAME = 'JonahHensley'
CONSUMER_KEY = keys['consumer_key']
CONSUMER_SECRET = keys['consumer_secret']
ACCESS_TOKEN = keys['access_token']
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = keys['access_token_secret']

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

followers = api.followers_ids(SCREEN_NAME)

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Yes', self)
        btn.clicked.connect(follower.follow(self))

        btn.resize(180, 40)
        btn.move(20, 35)

        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('No', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        qbtn.resize(180, 40)
        qbtn.move(20, 80)

        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.show()



class follower(QtGui.QWidget):
    def follow(self):
        while True:
            try:
              for f in followers:
                  UserFollow = input("Follow users from:  ")
                  print('Getting followers from ' + UserFollow)
                  api.wait_on_rate_limit = True
                  api.wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True
                  requests_cache.install_cache(cache_name='twitter_cache', backend='sqlite', expire_after=180)
                  print("followed {0}".format(api.get_user(f).screen_name))

                  api.create_friendship(f)
                  randnum = randint(10, 25)
                  randnumdisplay = print("Delaying next follow for " + str(randnum) + " seconds.")

                  print(str(randnumdisplay))
                  screen_names = [api.get_user(f).screen_name]
                  time.sleep(randnum)

            except tweepy.TweepError:
                print("Waiting till next interval...")

                time.sleep(60 * 15)

                continue
            except StopIteration:


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()             break


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Follower doesn't have to derive from QWidget. I also don't see where you create an instance of the follower class.